# Libgdx Remove Object After Collision Detection

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to remove object when they collision with my bird but I cannot do it but I do not know the why I cannot.

Here is my code:

```
if (Intersector.overlaps(this.birdCircle, this.enemyRectangle[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(this.birdCircle, this.enemyRectangle2[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(this.birdCircle, this.enemyRectangle3[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(this.birdCircle, this.enemyRectangle4[i]) || this.gameTime == 0.0F) {
           // this.gameState = 2;
        }
```

How can I remove enemies. (Also `enemyRectangle[i] = altEngel`) `altEngel` is a Texture and they are not in an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove something in libgdx, use the `dispose()` method if there is one for the thing you are trying to get rid of. You can set things without a `dispose()` method to null, getting rid of the references, and the garbage collector will get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

Libgdx has a special class for this purposes - `DelayedRemovalArray<>` 
It works like ArrayList:

```
DelayedRemovalArray<> array;
```

after collision you can delete your object:

```
array.removeIndex(i);
```

Write more information if you want detailed answer